# Writing a batch script to find the length of the string and pad zeros

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to find the length of the string that encloses numbers and based on that value I would like to pad zeros. But I have been facing issues.

What I'm trying to do:
-> I have csv file containing 3 value fields seperated by a comma and I need to check each of these variables whether they are bigger or smaller than a number for further processing like

```
368,0,2334
0,42,2000
24,215,0
```

-> Based on the string length I want to pad them with zeros respectively before I make a comparision with another 4 digit number (Four digit number is fixed) for further processing

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%a IN (data.csv) DO (

    set sum1="%%~a"
    set sum2="%%~b"
    set sum3="%%~c"

    set "MYSTRING=!sum1!"
    (echo "!MYSTRING!" & echo.) | findstr /O . | more +1 | (set /P RESULT= & call exit /B %%RESULT%%)
    set /A STRLENGTH=%ERRORLEVEL%-5
    >> length.csv echo string "!MYSTRING!" length = !STRLENGTH!
```

similarly to other variables too. I get results as below.

```
Output:
string "388" length = -5
string "401" length = -5
string "693" length = -5
string "0" length = -5
string "0" length = -5
```

some other outputs using the string length problems on this site also reults like

```
ECHO is Switched OFF
ECHO is Switched OFF
ECHO is Switched OFF

Expected Output:
string "388" length = 3
string "401" length = 3
string "6934" length = 4
```

Then I want to pad zeros to 2 or 3 digits numbers and make them 4 digits like 0388, 0401 respectively and leave the 4 digits numbers as they are to make comparision with the data.

Can anyone please guide me where I'm going wrong?

Why is that here variable stored in sum1 has to be enclosed between !sum1! and not %sum1% ? (Did wrong initially and coulldn't even save the values to a variable in order to calculate the length)
I'm also very new to Batch scripting.

Thank you. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: findstr does not return a length for the string. To find a string length, you will need to either build your own string length macro / subroutine or use one from [one of the many answers on this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+%22string+length%22)

Comment: There are no columns in a CSV file, those are fields, and the `C` stands for comma, which means that you've provided us with `3` fields, not one. In order for us to better understand, what may be a complex user case, you need to post the real world, actual, csv content, formatted appropriately in order for us to replicate your issue and offer reasonable solutions. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61270836/edit) to provide that content.

Comment: I have tried all the string length finding solutions provided but none of them worked for me. The data i have depicted here is how I have in my csv file. So you are right I have 3 fields seperated by comma.

Comment: It's good that you've now modified your question to be three fields, however you still need to modify the contents, currently the first and third records have a first field seven characters in length, and the second record has a first field which is six characters in length, _(due to space padding.)_ It would also help if you explain why you need to pad them with zeroes just to make a comparison, or more to the point, why you need to determine their length first, could you not simple prepend each with `1000` then use the last four characters of each for your comparison?

Comment: I have indented your batch file code, to highlight that is is incomplete, please can you complete it as necessary.

Comment: The number I have to compare these values aginst are 4 digits numbers. If you compare if 9 > 23 without padding 9 with 0 and making it '09' it will actually say 9 is greater than 23 and hence I have to pad the number before making comparision

Comment: I'm aware of how to compare numbers, what I'm telling you is that there's no real need to count them. You've already told us that your known base is four characters, so if you add/pad with three zeroes, then use the last four characters, no counting is needed.

Comment: @Pavan, I've once again added those indentations, please stop removing them, you can do so once you've fixed the code, to close the parenthsized block.

Comment: oh that is actually a great idea. I will re write the code and check .Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @compo I'm getting into trouble if I want to perform addition after padding the number. The error says " Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)". Any idea why?

Comment: @Pavan, that is to be expected, it is a 'feature' of `Set /A`. In this case, for addition, that means, performing your arithmetic before padding with leading zero's, or pad each with `100000`, _(the `1` will ensure that it isn't mistaken as octal)_, perform your arithmetic, then remove the required leading zero's as needed.

Comment: @compo The result after addition is very dynamic. Its not predictable whether it will be a 4 digit or 5 digit or 6 digit number. Is there any way that after I make the comparision I force it to consider the octal number as decimal and then make addition?

Comment: I know, that is why I told you to use `100000`. I told you that because even if you add the two largest four digit numbers, `9999 + 9999` the maximum length will always be catered for, i.e. `19998` padded with `100000`will always be okay. If of course you're adding a number of unknown maximum length, you've got a lot more work to do, possibly changing your entire script to not use the built-in `set /a` command, or better, use a scripting language which is better capable of working with your math.

Comment: For safety, I often go at least one additional zero than needed, that way, it's easier to always remove any leading `1`, then all leading zero's as needed. So perhaps `1000000` would be safer for you, it always depends upon what exactly you're using `set /a` for. Anyhow, I don't want this conversation to continue straying from the initial question, so if you have a specific user case, requiring assistance, please submit a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based upon my comment, *(padding then using the last four characters)*:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=]," %%G In ('"%__APPDIR__%find.exe /V /N ""<"data.csv""') Do @(
    Set /A record%%G]field[1]=1000%%H,record%%G]field[2]=1000%%I,record%%G]field[3]=1000%%J
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!record%%G]field[1]:~-4!,!record%%G]field[2]:~-4!,!record%%G]field[3]:~-4!
    EndLocal)
@Pause
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @compo. Your solution helped me a lot